# add page_type to slider so it recognizes page id's - Food Recipe Theme

Tags: wordpress, slider

Here is my code for the basic slider. I am trying to add the ability to enter in page_id's as well as post id's so my slider can help promote pages as well as recipe/ posts I create. Please let me know if you need further information. Here is my code:

```
<ul class="cycle-slideshow"  data-cycle-fx=scrollHorz data-cycle-timeout=4000 data-cycle-slides="li" data-cycle-pager=".cycle-pager">

                                            <?php

                                                        foreach( $slides as $slide )
                                                        {

                                                                $bs_slider_args = array( 'post_type'=> array('post','recipe') , 'posts_per_page' => 1, 'post__in' => array($slide['id']) );

                                                                $bs_slider_query = new WP_Query( $bs_slider_args );
                                                                if ( $bs_slider_query->have_posts() )
                                                                while ( $bs_slider_query->have_posts() ) :
                                                                    $bs_slider_query->the_post();
                                                                        ?>
                                                                        <li>
                                                                                <img src="<?php echo $slide['image']; ?>" alt="<?php the_title(); ?>" />
                                                                                <div class="about">
                                                                                        <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                                                                        <p><?php echo word_trim(get_the_excerpt(),28,'...'); ?></p>
                                                                                        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" class="readmore"><?php _e('Read more', 'FoodRecipe'); ?></a>
                                                                                </div>
                                                                        </li>
                                                                        <?php
                                                                endwhile;
                                                        }
                                        ?>

                                    </ul>
```

Comment: Do you want to pass multiple ids with different post type?

Comment: Eeee I don't want to mislead you. I need the admin side to accept page id's not just post id's. The end goal is to have the ability to promote a recipe or a page of some kind if we choose. I just don't want to hard code this all and then be the only one who can support it. I am too new to Wordpress to feel I can just go in and edit this theme that much.

Comment: Sorry I tried to post an image and it says I need at least a 10 rating.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you want to display this slider in homepage then create custom field(ABC).

Now put all multiple ids(3257, 2142, 941 like this) in custom field(ABC) in homepage in admin site and use below coding  to get custom field(ABC) in coding side.

```
   <?php 
$mutliplearray = array();
$mutliplearray = get_post_meta($homepage->ID, 'ABC' true ); // get the value of custom field ABC 
   ?>
```

So now your array will look like this.

```
 $mutliplearray = array(3257, 2142, 941);
```

Now do the query thing.

```
  $query = array('post__in' => $mutliplearray, 'posts_per_page' => 10, 'post_type' => array('post', 'page', 'receipe'));
     query_posts($query);
     while (have_posts()) :the_post();
             the_title(); // put content here.
    endwhile;
```

Comment: This did not work. Is there possibly something in the admin side only allowing recipe posts and not allowing page id's to be entered?

Comment: I got this to work:

'$li_slider_args = array( 'post_type'=> array('post', 'page', 'recipe') , 'post__in' => $slide );
         $li_slider_query = new WP_Query( $li_slider_args );'